# I am trying to deploy a React app from Github to Azure web app

Tags: azure, github, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have pushed my react app into Github repo. It is a basic app that I created using "create react app" to test a deployment. I am trying to deploy it to Azure web app. However I am getting an error message and the web app is not being displayed.

Here is what I've done so far.

This is file structure for the React app:

[image]

In azure web app, I go to **deployment center** and set the **repository** to a link of the repo as well as the **branch** to main

When I go to the url for my web app it says ":( Applicatio error". inside of the logs I get these errors

2023-10-05T21:47:56.920Z ERROR - Container frontenddemo_0_3401dbf7 for site frontenddemo has exited, failing site start

2023-10-05T21:47:56.929Z ERROR - Container frontenddemo_0_3401dbf7 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Edit: here is the .yml file

```
name: NodeJS with Webpack

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x, 18.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - name: Build
      run: |
        npm install
        npx webpack
```

Comment: do I need to create the .yml file? I don't se it

Comment: it doesn't have even have a `package`. i've posted the code above.

Comment: @user3424367 - Are you deploying to Azure Windows or Linux App Service ?

Comment: linux app service

Comment: @user3424367 - Ok...will check from my end and let you know.

Comment: Iam able to deploy and run the app without any issues.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/IG0O4Xa.png).Add Startup command `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon` command in the Configuration section.Will post an answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @[Edison Garcia](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/) for the clear steps.

***Check the below steps to Deploy the basic React pp to Azure Linux App service using GitHub Actions.***

I have followed the same steps mentioned by Edison Garcia to create a react app.

```cs
npx create-react-app reactoct
cd reactoct
```

- Run the `npm run build` command. Build folder will be created in the root directory of the Application. Instead of pushing all the files to Azure you need to use `build` folder in the  path.

[image]

- Open `.gitignore` file and remove the below lines to include the build folder in the GitHub Repo.

```cs
# production
/build
```

- Create a new GitHub Repository. Commands to push the local code to GitHub will be available in the new GitHub Repo Page.

```cs
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourGitHubName/MyApp.git
git push -u origin main
```

- As we have done changes in the `.gitignore` file to include `build` folder, we need to add that as well.Run the below commands.

```cs
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin main
```

- Now you can check `build` folder is included in the `GitHub` Repo.

[image]

- Create a new `Azure Linux App Service`.
- When you select the GitRepo from the Deployment center, a default `.yml` file under `.git/workflows`  will be created in the GitHub Repo (default template).
- We need to change the default `yml` template path from `.` to `build/`.

```cs
- name: Upload artifact for deployment job
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: node-app
      path: build/
```

- In Git Hub Repo cancel the running workflow, Edit the `yml` file path to `build/`  => save and commit the changes,
- In Azure App Service, add `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --spa --no-daemon` command in the `Configuration` => `General Settings` => `Startup Command`.
- Also enable the `Basic Auth Publishing Credentials` option.

[image]

***My `.yml` file:***

```cs
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - React11Oct

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: build/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'React11Oct'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_E194E92742C24133961AB59ECD48DA31 }}
          package: .
```

- Now re-run the failed jobs.

[image]

***Deployed App Output:***

[image]