# How to run npm install from Github Actions while deploying to Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions, npm-install

I have a .Net Core Web application with some npm packages. Therefore I have a `package.json` file in the root of my project and if I run `npm install` locally a folder called `node_modules` is created. The needed files from this folder are provided by `UseStaticFiles`. So far so good, everything works fine locally.

Now I'm deploying this app to a Azure App Service automatically from GitHub Actions. I use a workflow yaml file created in the Azure Deployment Center. The workflow do two things:

1. Build, publish and upload the artifact for the .Net application
2. Download the artifacts on Azure and deploy to my Azure Web App

Everything works fine, except of the npm packages of course.

So I add another build step to the workflow to run `npm install` after deployment directly on Azure:

```
- name: npm install
  run: npm install
```

If the GitHub Action is executed I can see that `npm install` is executed and installed some packages:

[image]

But if I open my application in the browser I get errors in the console because the resources from node_modules not found. I check the wwwroot of my App Service by Kudo (`<myapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot`) and indeed there is no node_modules folder. I guess that `npm install` is executed in the wrong directory and I know that I can specify a `working-directory` for `npm-install` build step, but I don't know to which directory I need to set it.

Does anybody had the same problem or knows how to successfully run `npm install` from a GitHub Action while deploying to Azure?

Comment: Do you have any node modules in  your .Net Core Web application

Comment: Could you show how do you configure .net app to use static content?

Comment: @Alexander Vogt Could you please share your `pacakge.json` file and `.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Iam able to push the `node_modules` folder when I deploy App using GitHub Actions.

Make sure the `node_modules` folder is pushed to GitHub repo.

Refer Git Commands from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271013/19648279) to push the local directory to Git.

[image]

[image]

- When I add the GitRepo ,in the default `yml` file the path is set to `${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp` ,
  Change the path to `.` and re-run the job.

> I know that I can specify a `working-directory` for `npm-install` build step, but I don't know to which directory I need to set it.

- The working-directory for `npm-install` has to be set to the path where `package.json` resides, i.e.., the root folder of the Application.
  So, you need to set  `.` , which indicates the root directory.
- To make sure to push the `node_modules` folder to root directory you can even use the [copy command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cp-command-linux-examples/) `cp` along with path.

***KUDU*** [image]

Refer the [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76580742/19648279) to install `npm-install` in `yml` file.