# deploy React project to Azure free plan

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a React project to Azure using Github, FTP and zip file, and none are seems to be working. I build the site in VS and uploaded the files/folders to root directory. kind of worked, but when I click refresh it keeps saying "resource not found". has any body deploy react to Azure?
let me know please. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your github repo?

Answer (score 1):

I created a React application using the following commands:

`npx create-react-app my-react-app`

I successfully ran the React application using the `npm start` command.

[image]

Using the `npm run build` command, the application is successfully built.
The React application is successfully deployed to the Azure portal using the steps below:

- During the deployment of the React application, `only the build folder is selected`, not the entire React application. See below:

[image]
[image]

[image]

deployment status in azure portal. Check below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Another approach to deploying an app service via GitHub Actions to refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271013/21525734) .

Comment: Pavan. Thank for your reply. I end up ftp the build folder to the Azure webapp server.
but as i mentioned when i refresh a page it gave me and resource not found. so i end up using hash as baseline in app.js "<BrowserRouter baseline="./#" > and it seems to be working

Comment: I recommend reading the quick start for NodeJS environment such as react on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode and please tell me on which stage do you encounter any issue